# Non-elementary antiderivative of rational function: $f(x)= \frac{1}{a_nx^n+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+\cdots+a_1x+a_0}$

Tags: calculus, integration, elementary-functions

Is there any function of the form $$f(x)= \frac{1}{a_nx^n+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+\cdots+a_1x+a_0}$$ for $n\in\mathbb{N},a_i\in\mathbb{R}$, that has no elementary antiderivative?

If there is none, is there a proof of that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every such function has an antiderivative expressible with elementary functions. You factor the denominator into a product of linear and quadratic factors and decompose using partial fractions.

Of course this is theoretical and neither practical nor closed form unless you  have a closed form solution for the roots of the denominator.

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_integrals_of_rational_functions

Comment: What about a quintic (or higher order function) with no closed form factorization?

Comment: Any  quintic denominator has five roots, so there is a partial fraction decomposition. The fact that you may not have a way to write those roots nicely as a function of the coefficients does not make the indefinite integral non-elementary. That's why I wrote the second paragraph in the answer.

Comment: Using wolfram to calculate the antiderivative of $\frac{1}{x^5+x+1}$ the solution involved some non rational functions, so I am not sure about the the first assertion of the answer

Comment: @EthanBolker indeed, the anti derivative can consist of arctangents due to quadratic rational functions, so instead of "Every such function has a rational antiderivative" I think you meant "Every such function has an elementary antiderivative"

Comment: @BenjaminWang Yes. A typo, now fixed. You could have.

Comment: @MattanFeldman See my response to another comment.

Comment: (1) "Elementary function" includes all constant functions.  Even constants where the value is not expressed in terms of rationals by radicals. (2) "Elementary function" includes all algebraic functions, including those not expressible in terms of rationals by radicals.